# What's the purpose by returning back the bad outliers from AdaBoost?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, boosting, adaboost

Assume that you having a matrix $X$ that holds both numerical and binary data. You plug in the data $X$ into AdaBoost and AdaBoost update the $X$ by only focusing on the rows that could not make a correct classifiction.

So the matrix $X$ will end up with rows that belongs to outliers, right?
Example:

If I have 10 rows inside $X$ and only two of them make a bad classification becuase they are "outliers". My $X$ will end up with a lot of these two rows becuase AdaBoost will increase their weights a lot because they make a bad classification.

If they have a large weight, the propability for re-train the rows are higher than the propability of correct classificated rows.